# Create a new array object from existing

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of object "myData". I need to create a new array of object "newMyData"

Following is the "myData"

```
     myData = [
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         },
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         }, .........
        ]
```

I need to create dynamically new array of object like following below from "myData"

```
newMyData = [
         {
          "mainImage": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbImage": "~/thumbnail/test.png"
         },
        {
          "mainImage": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbImage": "~/thumbnail/test.png"
         }, .........
]
```

What is the javascript function I need to write? how to loop through all the nodes.

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: Google `javascript .map()` - this allows you to map an array to new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myNewData = myData.map(data => ({
    mainImage: data.PictureUrl,
    thumbImage: data.ThumbnaiUrl // please, use lowerCase for properties.
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array map:

```js
     myData = [
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         },
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         }, 
        ];
var newMyData = myData.map(current=>{
    var obj = {};
    obj.mainImage = current.PictureUrl;
    obj.ThumbImage = current.ThumbnailUrl;
    return obj;
});
console.log(newMyData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can simply iterate over your array using `Arrays.forEach()` and get the required value in map and finally push this map into your new array like following:

```js
var newMyData = [];
var myData = [
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         },
         {
          "PictureUrl": "~/images/test.png",
          "ThumbnailUrl": "~/thumbnail/test.png",
          "Date": "02/08/2018",
          "Time": "09.00.00AM",
          "ImageName": "NewImage"
         }
        ];
myData.forEach(function(data) {
    var newMap = {};
    newMap.mainImage = data.PictureUrl;
    newMap.ThumbImage = data.ThumbnailUrl;
    newMyData.push(newMap);
});

console.log(newMyData);
```